# MKMapView to deny single touch panning

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

I need to allow two-finger pinch/rotate/panning and deny single-finger panning.

I've tried some ways to achieve this:

```
for (UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan in mapView.gestureRecognizers) {
    if ([pan isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        if ([pan minimumNumberOfTouches] < 2) {
            [pan setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
        }
    }
}
```

But this not works. Maybe some kind of `UIGestureRecognizer` failing dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found nice solution:

```
self.twoFingerPan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
self.twoFingerPan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
self.twoFingerPan.delegate = self;
[self addGestureRecognizer:self.twoFingerPan];

...

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer == self.twoFingerPan &&
        [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]] &&
        (otherGestureRecognizer.view == self.mapView ||
         otherGestureRecognizer.view.superview == self.mapView)) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

And addition to allow any outer scrolling:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer == self.twoFingerPan &&
        [otherGestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```